# error: could not compile `sc-network` when compiling my parachain node in v0.9.32

Tags: parachain, substrate-contracts-node, cumulus

I'm compiling using the v0.9.32, any hint or solution?

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `derive_prelude` in `swarm`
  --> /home/amrm/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/5ea6d95/client/network/src/behaviour.rs:58:10
   |
58 | #[derive(NetworkBehaviour)]
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ could not find `derive_prelude` in `swarm`
   |
   = note: this error originates in the derive macro `NetworkBehaviour` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0432]: unresolved import `libp2p`
  --> /home/amrm/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/5ea6d95/client/network/src/behaviour.rs:58:10
   |
58 | #[derive(NetworkBehaviour)]
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ could not find `derive_prelude` in `swarm`
   |
   = note: this error originates in the derive macro `NetworkBehaviour` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0432, E0433.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0432`.
error: could not compile `sc-network` due to 2 previous errors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in `libp2p`. They had released a breaking change as patch release. It fixed now in [libp2p](https://github.com/libp2p/rust-libp2p/pull/3178) and they also yanked the problematic crate. Make sure that you are using version `0.30.2` of `libp2p-swarm-derive`. Reverting your `Cargo.lock` should fix it.